# Ошибка при сборке проекта на webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack2

При запуске сборки в консоль вылетает вот такая ошибка:

> throw new _ValidationError2.default(ajv.errors, name)

Сам так и не смог разобраться. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять что не так и как исправить.

Полный вид ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот конфиг:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        backup: './app/scripts/backupBase/backupDB',
        newOrder: './app/scripts/newOrder/newOrder',
        searchOrder: './app/scripts/searchOrder/searchOrder',
        redact: './app/scripts/redactOrder/redactOrder',
        mainPageCss: './app/css/mainPage.css'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build/js',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                }]
            },
            {
                test:   /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: 'css-loader'
                    })
            }, {
                test:   /\.(png|jpg|svg|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]'
            }]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            disabled: false,
            allChunks: true})
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/

изменил строку на массив:
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'] })